# Python Program to print Diamond pattern for input numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns

I want this output:

```
         1 

     0      0

 1       1       1 

      0      0

         1
```

My code:

```
    n=2
k = 2 * n - 2
x = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    x += 1
    for j in range(0, k):
        print(end=" ")
    k = k - 1
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        if(x==2):
            print(0,end=" ")
        else:
            print(1, end=" ")
    print("\r")
k = n - 2
x = n + 2
for i in range(n, -1, -1):
    x -= 1
    for j in range(k, 0, -1):
        print(end=" ")
    k = k + 1
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        if(x==2):
            print(0,end=" ")
        else:
            print(x, end=" ")
    print("\r")
```

For the above code I am getting output:

```
    1 

  0   0 

3   3   3 

 0    0 

    1
```

Comment: Sounds like there's a bug in your program, then. By the way, is your desired output asymmetrical on purpose? (The 2nd and 4th line are different.)

Comment: Btw, you tag Python 2.7, but your code is definitely Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
n = 2
k = 2 * n - 2
x = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    x += 1
    for j in range(0, k):
        print(end=" ")
    k = k - 1
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        if x == 2:
            print(0, end=" ")
        else:
            print(1, end=" ")
    print("\r")
k = n - 2
x = n + 2
for i in range(n, -1, -1):
    x -= 1
    for j in range(k, 0, -1):
        print(end=" ")
    k = k + 1
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        if x == 2:
            print(0, end=" ")
        else:
            print(1, end=" ") #HERE PRINT 1 INSTEAD OF x
    print("\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the empty lines between every printed line, which are trivial to add, this seems to do the trick.

```
# Tunable parameters
n = 2
space = 3

# No need to modify below
spacer = " " * space
for y in range(n * 2 + 1):
    w = (n + 1) - abs(n - y)
    c = "0" if y % 2 else "1"
    print(spacer.join(c * w).center((space + 2) * n))
```